# Is there a web service that does reverse FirstBits lookup?

Tags: firstbits

Input: any old Bitcoin address e.g.

1BCNEPySL4gzzjg8NNyNsQYJWYmZwpgaPF

Output: the FirstBits, in this case **1BCN1u**

Comment: can you please tell where I can read about old and new bitcoin addresses?

Comment: @SalvadorDali - I don't understand what you mean "old and new addresses"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blockchain.info has APIs to generate and resolve firstbits.

Get firstbits,

http://blockchain.info/q/getfirstbits/1BCNEPySL4gzzjg8NNyNsQYJWYmZwpgaPF

Get address,

http://blockchain.info/q/resolvefirstbits/1paypal

http://blockchain.info/q/resolvefirstbits/1ebay

http://blockchain.info/q/resolvefirstbits/1google

Comment: What is the purpose of this?

Comment: @bvpx:        Https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Firstbits tells us that firstbits are basically a way for bitcoin users to type a few less key strokes (an address shortner for bitcoin addresses). However there are more than a few downsides to it. I hope the information is helpful.n Just start at the beginning and learn everything bitcoin wiki touches on. Feel reese to ask more questions. I always suggest using the search engine before posting so you keep good rep. You can always privately message me. But I am over on my altcoins pool mostly.

Comment: This service seems to be out of order currently.

Answer (score 1):

Having seen that yes blockchain.info no longer offers this service I was able to find only one other Block explorer that do offer the FirstBit lookup on addresses:

https://www.walletexplorer.com

https://www.walletexplorer.com/address/1BCN1ugdKdWd9pQ8Am9hMhtHZfmbXzxE8a?from_firstbits=1BCN1u

Hope this helps :)